# R Shiny - how can I pass a select input from UI and into quo() in server file?

Tags: r, shiny, rlang

I have made a plot function, called make_figure. This function takes in the variable name of the variable I want to plot, among other things. But the function is made so that I need to use quo() around the variable name when I call it. Like this:

```
make_figure(quo(variableName))
```

This works fine.

Now I want to implement the function into a Shiny application, but I am not able to find a way to pass the variable name from the UI and into quo() in the server file.

Sketch of function structure as called in Shiny server file, if I could have called it as I normally do (outside of Shiny):

```
output$fig <-renderPlot({ 
 make_figure(quo(input$chosenVariable))
})
```

This does of course not work as the quo(input$chosenVariable) just quotes input$chosenVariable instead of  variableName (quo(variableName)), which is what I really want it to do.

My Shiny UI file looks something like this:

```
selectInput(
 inputId = "chosenVariable"
 label = "Variable"
 choices = c("Variable Display Name" = "variableName")
)
```

I want to pass variableName from choices into the function at the server side. **I have tried a dozen different combinations of !!, quo(), quo_get_expr() around  variableName at both the server and the UI side of the application, without success.**

For instance I tried:

UI:

```
selectInput(
  inputId = "chosenVariable"
  label = "Variable"
  choices = c("Variable Display Name" = quo_get_expr(quo(quo(variableName)))
)
```

Server:

```
output$fig <-renderPlot({ 
 make_figure(input$chosenVariable))
})
```

The rationale was that quo_get_expr(quo(quo(variableName))) returns quo(variableName). However this expresseion was not allowed in choices in selectInput.

**How can I solve this?**

**Remember that my make_figure function is made so that I need to passe quo(variableName) into it.**

Comment: Please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that someone can help you.

Comment: I would rather change `make_figure()` in a way that it accepts bare names (e.g. `xvar`) or strings (e.g. `"xvar"`). Neither would be a problem in shiny and it would also be easier to call the function, since you wouldn't need to use `quo()` every time.

Comment: Try with `!!sym(input$...)` instead of `quo()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing make_figure so that it accepts normal variable names sounds wisest, as suggested by TimTeaFan.

I found that the conversion of the variable to the needed "quo format", inside the function, could be done by putting a couple of lines in the beginning of the function:

```
make_figure <- function(variableName){

     variableName <- sym({{noquote(variableName)}})
     variableName <- quo({{variableName}})

     (...Excluded: Addional code that now can make use
     of the the variable that now had the needed "quo format"...)

}
```

Probably a cleaner way to do this (if you know one, please comment), but at least this works.